# Error during installing apk to virtual device on Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, gradle

Im getting this error during apk installation on android studio. It appears to be an error with the manifest file. Before getting this error I got another error due to a declared xml file in my manifest which I had deleted prior. After deleting the field as suggested by android studio, my project was built however during installation I got this error. Below is the log during the apk installation.

> 5:23 PM   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project
>   D:\Documents\projects_and_practice\HowNormalAmI
>
> 5:23 PM   Gradle build finished in 12 s 73 ms
>
> 5:23 PM   Failed to commit install session 1049913730 with command cmd
>   package install-commit 1049913730. Error:
>   INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
>   installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1049913730.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
>   file line #28):  requires an android:value or
>   android:resource attribute
>
> 5:23 PM   Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
>                 The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
>                 Retry

Here is my manifest file. All I have is one activity, two layouts and some views, I also have google firebase setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hownormalami">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Before I had an xml decleration in my meta-data tag. The xml file was deleted however the decleration was still present in my meta-data section. Not sure if that was the cause and if it is how can I fix it?

Edit: It was the culprit, as far as I understand every "name" tag in meta data requires an accompanying "value" tag. I have since deleted the meta data field altogether, however my app simply crashes upon launching now.

Edit: App will run on no emulator, android AVD will not even boot up anymore, bluestacks wont work either. Not sure what's the issue.

Comment: Edit, I did not edit my gradle, I edited my manifest. The example posted below is my manifest not gradle.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might notice that you may edit your own posts. No need to add further details as comment. ;-)

Comment: thank you! noticed late haha.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to figure it out. My initial problem was due to my meta data tag. Android studio would not install my app because meta data contained a key but no value, i.e meta data runs on key value pairs and I didn't provide a value line. Deleting the key and leaving the meta data tag empty also resolved in an error. I deleted the entire meta data tag as it was not needed at this moment for my application. All errors after that, were due to errors in my java code. Fixing those errors got my app running again.